# Reserved IP for Azure Cloud Service doesn't persist

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-cloud-services

I'm struggling to get to grips with Reserved IP addresses in an Azure Cloud Service.

I have a Cloud Service with Staging and Productions deployments and I need at least the Production deployment to have a stable IP address. I set up 2 Reserved IP addresses as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/) then assigned my reserved IPs to the Production and Staging deployments with Power Shell:

```
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP1 -ServiceName mycloudservice -Slot “Production”
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP2 -ServiceName mycloudservice -Slot “Staging”
```

All well and good the reserved IPs get assigned to the respective instances and swapping maintains the correct addresses. The problem is if I delete one of the deployments and redeploy the IP address is not maintained.

I also tried assigning a reserved IP address to the cloud service without specifying a "Slot" and it assigned fine but does not seem to get used in either Production or Staging deployments.

```
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP -ServiceName mycloudservice
```

My usual workflow would be to deploy to Staging then swap with Production once I have tested all is working fine. With this scenario how can I ensure the Production deployment always gets a Reserved IP address when I swap from Staging, even if there is no current Production instance deployed?

The Azure documentation says "IP address for the cloud service will be the same even as resources are shutdown or deallocated" so shouldn't my previously assigned Production IP address be maintained even if I delete the Production instance and then swap from Staging?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

Create your reserved IPs

`New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "ip1" -Location "East US 2"`

`New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "ip2" -Location "East US 2"`

Deploy to the production slot with the following network configuration in your .cscfg file:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <ReservedIPs>
        <ReservedIP name="ip1" />
      </ReservedIPs>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
```

Deploy to the staging slot with the following configuration:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <ReservedIPs>
        <ReservedIP name="ip2" />
      </ReservedIPs>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
```

Continue using your normal workflow - deploy to staging, then swap to production.  The IP addresses should stay associated with their slots (ip1 in production and ip2 in staging).

Comment: If I do that and deploy to Staging what will happen when I swap the Staging and Production instances?

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. After performing these initial deployments what do you have in the .cscfg NetworkConfiguration for subsequent Staging deployments (which then get switched to Production)? Also does this method maintain the Production IP even if you delete the Production instance and switch from Staging?

Comment: In this example, subsequent deployments have a ReservedIP name of "ip2".  If I delete the production deployment, then redeploy to production with "ip1", the initial reserved VIP address is restored.

Comment: Using the .cscfg files does work as you say but in effect does the same thing as my assigning the reserved IP address to the running instances. I never deploy directly to production and only swap from staging, which will maintain the reserved IP in production as long as there is a production instance running. If for whatever reason there is no production instance running when I swap from staging then my reserved IP is not used. Azure docs say the IP should be maintained even if "resources are shutdown or deallocated". Question edited to make this clearer.

Comment: In my deployment scenario, I always deploy to staging.  Since that is the case, I should associate a reserved IP with the production slot via powershell, and use my staging reserved IP in the .cscfg file. Is this correct?