# Swapping deployment slots with Azure reserved IP

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, static-ip-address, azure-deployment-slots

I have a cloud service (classic model) and I need to assign a public static IP address to it.
I created it through PowerShell `New-AzureReservedIP` cmdlet and associated with cloud service.

Deployment itself is performed via Azure PowerShell and uses Staging and Production slots swap.
My question is whether slots swap is able to coexist with reserved IPs.

Assume, I created 2 IPs (for Production and Staging slots accordingly):
`MyService_ProdSlot` and `MySerice_StagingSlot`.
I suppose, I have now to create also 2 `.cscgf` files to deploy: for Production and Staging as well.

What should I specify in the `ReservedIP` element (taking into account that each deployment will swap the addresses and once swapped the Staging IP won't conform to what is specified in the config file anymore)?

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
  <AddressAssignments>
    <ReservedIPs>
      <ReservedIP name="???" />
    </ReservedIPs>
  </AddressAssignments>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

Furthermore, how should I tell Azure to use another `.cscfg` file when performing swap?

Answer (score 1):

The suggested process that is discussed in this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919192/reserved-ip-for-azure-cloud-service-doesnt-persist) is to deploy to both slots  directly with the .cscfg specifying their respective reserved ips. Then continue deploying to the staging slot with the .cscfg specifying the staging slots reserved ip and then swapping when ready.

I haven't tried this approach yet personally but will update this answer if I can verify it.

**Edit**

I have tried this now and can confirm it works.